# C++ OpenGL with Visual Studio Release-Config-Bug

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opengl, release

I'm using visual studio 2015 community edition and have a weird bug on compiling in release config (the bug does not show on debug config).
Actually i use opengl to simply create a shadowmap and then render the scene with that. As i said, compiling on the debug config the shadow is rendered.
But on release config, it just render the scene without shadow.

I searched a bit in the internet and found some informations about wrong configs.
But i have not the experience to play around with the configurations.
(and i dont want to destroy everything ;))
Can someone help me with this?

Comment: clearly UB / unitialized variables. Plz post your code

Comment: that was a quick one ... the constructor of my LightPlane-Class had one parameter which hadn't a name ... so it had used the "far variable of the class-instance ... thank you! without your advise i hadn't look on the parameters ;)

Comment: I think SO readers would be delighted if you posted a clear answer to your own question (this is encouraged). I failed to answer properly to a similar "debug OK / release KO" question today!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the constructor of my LightPlane-Class had one parameter which hadn't a name ... so it have used the "far" variable of the class-instance which wasn't intialized

```
LightPlane::LightPlane(glm::vec3& position, glm::vec3& lookAt, glm::vec3& up, GLfloat near,
                        GLfloat far, GLfloat fov, GLfloat aspect) {
                        //the "far"-parameter wasn't named
    this->far = far;
    this->near = near;
    this->position = position;
    this->fov = fov;
    view = glm::lookAt(position, lookAt, up);
    projection = glm::perspective(fov, aspect, near, far);
}
```